# how to equate items in the string-array android

Tags: android, arrays

i have two String arrays mylist and listprice.

```
 <string-array name="mylist">
    <item>Bottle</item>
    <item>Watch</item>
    <item>Books</item>
    <item>Mobile</item>
    <item>Purse</item>
    <item>Pen</item>
    <item>Glass</item>
    <item>Class</item>
    <item>Rubber</item>
    <item>Fan</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="listprice">
    <item>160</item>
    <item>2600</item>
    <item>200</item>
    <item>26000</item>
    <item>260</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>500</item>
    <item>3000</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>380</item>
</string-array>
```

i want to initilize both the arrays items such that "bottle" equals "160","watch" equals "2600"  and so on... how can i achieve it...thanks in advance...

Comment: access both arrays simultaneously in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hash map for both array relation:

```
   HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
               for (int i = 0; i < getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mylist).length; i++) {
                    map.put(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mylist)[i],getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listprice)[i]);
                }
```

Comment: thanks thats the code...now the question is i have mylist added in one spinner...and listprice added in another spinner if i change the value of one...another should change accordingly..

Comment: You can change second spinner index value by this: secondSpinner.setSelection(firstSpinnerPosition);

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] itemList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mylist);
String[] itemPrice = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listprice);
```

Now you can put all these in hashmap.

```
HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i<itemList.length; i++){
items.put(itemList[i], itemPrice[i]);
}
```

Now if you want to get price of Fan then just write

```
String price = items.get("Fan"); //it will be 380
```

OR you can make use of str.equals(str2) method for checking the item and then from the index getting the price from itemPrice array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your array like this:

```
String[] listprice = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listprice);
String[] mylist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access string arrays with below code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] mylist = res.getStringArray(R.array.mylist);
String[] listprice = res.getStringArray(R.array.listprice);
```

and you can use `mylist[index]` equals `listprice[index]`

Answer (score 0):

Take two strings and concatinate the values .

```
 private String[] concat(String[] A, String[] B) {
       int aLen = A.length;
       int bLen = B.length;
       String[] C= new String[aLen+bLen];
       System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, aLen);
       System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, aLen, bLen);
       return C;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can do something like with

```
String myList[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mylist);
String myListPrice[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listprice);
```

You can create a class lets say

```
public class ItemPrice{
      private String listItemName;
      private String listPrice;
      public String getListItemName(){return listItemName;}
      public String getListPrice(){return listPrice;}
      public void setListItemName(String itemName){this.listItemName = itemName;}
      public void setListPrice(String listPrice){this.listPrice = listPrice;}
}
```

Your array logic can be something like this

```
List<ItemPrice> itemPriceList = new ArrayList<ItemPrice>();
for(int i=0;i<myList.length;i++){
    ItemPrice items =  new ItemPrice();
    items.setListItemName(myList[i]);
    items.setListPrice(myListPrice[i]);
    itemPriceList.add(items);
}
```

So you can get the itemPriceList which will contain both item along with its price encapsulated in one object. I am assuming both array length will be same and are mapped according to their index.

Do share if this is what you are looking for and if you require further help?